# How to "focus zoom" on a spherical camera?

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, linear-algebra

So, for anyone familiar with Google Maps, when you zoom, it does it around the cursor.

That is to say, the matrix transformation for such a zoom is as simple as:

TST^{-1}*x

Where T is the translation matrix representing the point of focus, S the scale matrix and x is any arbitrary point on the plane.

Now, I want to produce a similar effect with a spherical camera, think [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/poisonous-cfba7da278eb41bc941022ca9ecebabe).

When you zoom in and out, the camera needs to be translated so as to give a similar effect as the 2D zooming in Maps. To be more precise, given a fully composed MVP matrix, there exists a set of parallel planes that are parallel to the camera plane. Among those there exists a unique plane P that also contains the center of the current spherical camera.

Given that plane, there exists a point x, that is the unprojection of the current cursor position onto the camera plane.

If the center of the spherical camera is c then the direction from c to x is d = x - c.

And here's where my challenge comes. Zooming is implemented as just offsetting the camera radially from the center, given a change in zoom Delta, I need to find the translation vector u, colinear with d, that moves the center of the camera towards x, such that I get a similar visual effect as zooming in google maps.

Since I know this is a bit hard to parse I tried to make a diagram:
[image]

TL;DR

I want to offset a spherical camera towards the cursor when I zoom, how do i pick my translation vector?

Comment: What requirements do you have for the zooming? As it stands, any length should produce a reasonable zoom. I usually calculate the distance as `d * (1-c^(zoom amount))`, where `d` is the current distance to the target, `c` is a positive constant smaller than 1 that defines how fast to zoom. And `zoom amount` is the user-defined amount to zoom (either positive or negative, can directly use the scroll wheel amount).

Comment: Zoom is currently implemented as offsetting the camera back and forth from the center of the spherical camera. It isn;t the zoom amount I am looking for, it;s the magnitude of the offset vector.

Comment: I suggested one method for that offset. Do you have any specific requirements for the offset? Otherwise, there does not seem to be a unique answer to your question.

Comment: I don;t think you are understanding the full scope of the problem. There's 2 actions going on, 2 offsets.

One is the zoom offset, the other is is an offset orthogonal to the first, from the center of the camera to the unprojection of the cursor onto that plane.

Given a zoom amount z, what is the magnitude of the orthogonal vector d?

Comment: Ok, I misinterpreted the "center" as the projection center of the camera. Why don't you just offset the camera along `x - cameraPosition`? This seems much more intuitive.

Comment: In a spherical camera, moving the center also moves the camera, so they are equivalent. The question is, how much should the camera be moved.

But your question I think just gave me the solution. You are right, if you want to move the camera along that direction, then you can decompose that vector into 2, the radial zoom and the orthogonal offset. And then given the zoom level you can calculate the magnitude of the other vector! Thanks!